# Play sound when other object(ball) hit cube

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class audio : MonoBehaviour
{
  public AudioClip hitsound;

  void  Update ()
  {
  }

  void  OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
  {
    if (other.tag == "Ball")
    {
        GetComponent.<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (hitsound);
    }
  }
}
```

I assign .mp3 file to inspector, and also, I added Audio Source component but I can't hear hit sound. Cubes which need to be destroyed is moving during game. I added that script and audio source component on parts which are not moving and when ball hit that non-moving parts, sound is playing (every time).

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: do your gameobjects have rigidbodys and coliders (also you probably should use [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html))

Comment: Yes, my all game objects have that components. Ok I will try this.

Comment: is there a chance you have a problem with the 2D / 3D sound settings?  where is your audio listener?

Answer (score 1):

## YOU HAVE A TYPO

## GetComponent.<

## SHOULD BE

## GetComponent<

---

Doesn't the . after GetComponent give you an error?

Anyway, make sure your colliders are set as triggers (checkbox on component).

Also I think Unity recommend using CompareTag() instead of ==.

It's worth putting a Debug.Log into the OnTriggerEnter2D to see if that is even firing.

Finally, make sure your colliders are the 2D versions, not just the regular colliders.

Comment: Hey bro, Debug.Log works, but I can't hear sound. Why is that? I checked all colliders and everything is good. I said before that I put the same script on other parts of game and it works, but dosen't work on moving object.

Comment: Can't do that because it shown errors. **I said before that I put the same script on other parts of game and it works** :)

Comment: Are you using Unity 4 or 5?  If 4, is your AudioClip set to "3D sound"?  It might be playing but you just can't hear it because the object is far away from the AudioListener on the camera.  If you're on Unity 5 check the volume and 3D sound settings on the AudioSource.

That's really weird that your don't get an error with the GetComponent line...